# setting the hue of an image using OpenGL on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to understand Apple's [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) example, specifically with the goal of changing the hue of an image.  I don't want to do a hue rotation, but rather a hue replacement (like kCGBlendModeHue).

I can figure out the linear interpolation, and parameterizing the hue, once I'm able to make the degenerate image.  Any pointers?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/glossary/ig/Blending-Modes/Blend-Hue.htm)?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, an equivalent of the hue blend mode is what I'm going for.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to consider using OpenGL ES 2 instead with a fragment shader?